# How to add tags to View-created RSS feed?

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms, feeds

How to add tags to View-created RSS feed?

I have added some tags to each of my articles, but the RSS feed generated by Views does not show the tags.

Answer (score 1):

You can include them in the fields for the view display. If they are taxonomy terms, you can add them from the views fields list.

Comment: but in RSS mode, it said, "The selected style or row format does not utilize fields."